# excel date format MMYYYY

Tags: excel, date

i have fiscal date MMYYYY that needs to be converted to a date mm/dd/yyyy. Since I don't have date in original data I can use 01 for entire column.  I have tried text to columns and have been unsuccessful. 
It can also me converted as mm-dd-yyyy or in any order as long as sepearated by - or a /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the text. If you have your date as Text formatted 'MMYYYY' in cell A1:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,2),1)
```